Unable to see Agreement Templates in Adobe Simple Sign Component in Experience Builder
I am trying to use Adobe Simple Sign Component in Experience builder to show Signature field for the user to sign , but On Inserting the Component , I am not able to see any Agreement Templates which I have already created from the Application ( Acrobat Sign for Salesforce )
I'm getting to see the error -
Please specify either an agreement template or an agreement record ID.
Steps I followed

https://helpx.adobe.com/in/sign/integrations/salesforce-simple-sign-guide.html#:~:text=Simple%20Sign%20is%20an%20effortless,it%20into%20other%20Lightning%20components.

Can Someone suggest , If it is possible to implement this is LWC or It needs to be in AURA Component itself ?



Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked with Adobe support or their community forums?

Yeah , I checked, In community forum I found 1 question but it has no answers , And Adobe Support team provides support to only Enterprise Editions.
